# Postgresql table with BigInt primary key column : slow insert

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a table with "BigInt"(int8) primaryKey column, insert on this table is extremely slow, and it's keep degrading as the number of rows increases.

Some more details:

- Postgres version: 10.7
- No separate index on table
- Number of inserts per min  ~2000, it degrades with more rows in data
- We have around 25k records, we tried by truncating data and inserting from zero row, but no improvement
- We use Spring-data-jpa to insert the data (.save()) method. SpringBoot: 2.2.4.RELEASE/Hoxton.SR1
- Hikari datasource with max-pool-size: 50.
- column is mapped to java.math.BigInteger in entity
- single row inserts (not batch)

The issue seems with BiGInt column itself, when we change the column type from BigInt to varchar, slowness disappeared, 25k records inserted in one minute.

am I doing anything wrong with BigInt column ? why BigInt type  makes insert so slow ?

any insights and help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can we have `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for a fast ans a slow insert? You can use `auto_explain` to get that.

Comment: how are you generating the primary key?

Comment: It gets slower with more rows, but doesn't get faster with less rows?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - here's explain output :   Insert on xxxx  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=1502) (actual time=0.122..0.122 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=12
  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=1502) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.038 ms
Execution time: 0.183 ms

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : This is how I create primary key: CREATE TABLE xxxx (
 id int8 NOT NULL,
 ...
 CONSTRAINT id_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

Comment: And how are you generating the values for the primary key?

Comment: But 0.183 milliseconds isn't bad at all. Try to get a slower execution. Please set `track_io_timing` to `on`, then `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` will show even more interesting data.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - I will try to get more details shortly, currently I dont have admin capabilities to enable  parameters, it' currently running on aws (arora postgres I dont think aws is an issue, as changing bigint to varchar works fine)..

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - Issue solved by mapping to Postgresql:BingInteger(int8) --> Java.lang.Long, million records insert takes less than 5 mins now. Though I didn't see Postgres column type to Java type mapping any where, got hint from one of the old mailing list.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was caused by wrong mapping:

`Postgresql:BingInteger(int8) --> Java.math.BigInteger` ❌

Correct Mapping

`Postgresql:BingInteger(int8) --> Java.lang.Long` ✅

Got hint from this post: [mailing-list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTinsk4rwT7v-751bwQkgTN1rkA=8uE-jk69nape-@mail.gmail.com)