# spring data jpa Query is taking very long time compared to same query when called using entity manager in postgres db?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am doing one simple select query from postgres DB. When I am executing that query using spring data jpa @Query inside JPA Repository, the query is taking around 6 seconds. When I executed the same query using entityManager.createNativeQuery, it is taking 600 ms. In my entity, there are no mappings also to other entity. I am not sure, why spring data jpa is taking that much time.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="transaction_history")
public class TransactionHistory {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private long transactionHistoryId;

    @Column(name = "TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID")
    private int transactionTypeId;

    @Column(name = "SUBSCRIPTION_ID")
    private BigInteger subscriptionId;

    @Column(name = "TRANSACTION_DATE")
    private Date transactionDate;
}
```

Query taking 6 seconds:

```
@Repository
public interface TransactionHistoryRespository extends JpaRepository<TransactionHistory, Long> {
    @Query(value =  "SELECT * FROM (SELECT *"
            + " FROM transaction_history"
            + " WHERE"
            + "      subscription_id = :subscriptionId"
            + "      AND TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID IN (209, 210, 212, 213)"
            + "      AND TOTAL_QUOTE_AMOUNT IS NOT NULL"
            + "      ORDER BY TRANSACTION_DATE DESC) AS transaction_history LIMIT 1"
            , nativeQuery = true)
    TransactionHistory findLastPaymentFailureBySubscriptionId(
            @Param("subscriptionId") BigInteger subscriptionId);

}
```

Query taking 600 milliseconds:

```
        javax.persistence.Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM (SELECT *" +
                "             FROM transaction_history\n" +
                "             WHERE" +
                "            subscription_id = 111901466\n" +
                "            AND TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID IN (209, 210, 212, 213)\n" +
                "            AND TOTAL_QUOTE_AMOUNT IS NOT NULL\n" +
                "            ORDER BY TRANSACTION_DATE DESC) AS transaction_history LIMIT 1");
        List resultList = query.getResultList();
```

I was expecting spring data jpa also should take 600 milliseconds only.

Comment: do you observe the same performance issue when passing `long` instead of `BigInteger`?

Comment: No, I'm just asking to check whether it reproduces with `long` datatype, if no, I have some thoughts on that.

Comment: A predicate `subscription_id = 111901466` is **not** the *same* as using a *bind variable*  `subscription_id = :subscriptionId`. The most probable explanation is that the former uses an index but the latter not. Post the two execution plans for the queries with the two predicates.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber The is an issue with bind variable. Below code is not taking more time. Is there any probability of issue with postgres jdbc driver ?

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT *" +
            "             FROM webs.transaction_history\n" +
            "             WHERE" +
            "            subscription_id = 111901466\n" +
            "            AND ...) AS transaction_history LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov When passing long as query parameter input instead of BigInteger for subscriptionId, this issue is not happening. Any idea why this was the case with postgres and not with oracle DB ?

@Param("subscriptionId") Long subscriptionId

Comment: Pls post the `DDL`of the table - data type of the column `SUBSCRIPTION_ID` and the index definition.

Comment: subscription_id int8 NULL

CREATE INDEX ix_tranhist_subid ON ONLY webs.transaction_history USING btree (subscription_id);

Comment: Please update your question with the requested information.

Answer (score -1):

The issue seem to be using `java.math.BigInteger` datatype for postgres `int8` column. After changing to `java.lang.Long` datatype, the query time reduced now.

Before code:

```
TransactionHistory findBySubscriptionId(
        @Param("subscriptionId") BigInteger subscriptionId);
```

Updated code:

```
TransactionHistory findBySubscriptionId(
       @Param("subscriptionId") Long subscriptionId);
```

Similar issue was reported here: [Postgresql table with BigInt primary key column : slow insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60679576/postgresql-table-with-bigint-primary-key-column-slow-insert)